# jmeter - how to use extracted value from response in Body Data of another request

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to use the extracted value in Body Data of another request. I extracted the value using JSON Path Extractor like below

[image]

value is extracted from the below response
[image]

I used it like this in Body data

```
  {
    "TransactionId": ${transactionId},
    "Cancelled": false
  }
```

but this is not working in **JMeter**  it shows the transactionId as ["223"].
I want it to be only 223

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can do this in different ways, but I prefer to use "Jmeter" functionality (better to avoid plugins). **For source git** [link](https://github.com/mcheepati/api/blob/master/json_parser_demo.jmx)

```
1. Using "Regular Expression Extractor" post processor.
2. Using "JSON Path PostProcessor" post processor.
```

1. "Regular Expression Extractor": Regular Expression Extractor is no of the best functionality.

   `Regular Expression:  "transactionId":"(.+?)" 
   Template: $1$ 
   Match Number: 1`

[image]
2."JSON Path PostProcessor": I never used this post processor, it's also good. Below is the expression

`JSON path Expression : $.transactionId
Match Numbers: 1`

[image]

Please find the Results in Debugger Sampler, in "view Results tree"

[image]

Comment: I want to write the extracted element to a file. The response JSON is : {"distance":14.518,"distanceUnit":"km","time":11.5,"timeUnit":"min"} In Json Extractor, I have given the variable name as ResponseTime. In BeanShell postprocessor, I am trying to access it as time = vars.get("ResponseTime"); But getting null. Am I doing anything wrong? please suggest

Answer (score 2):

Substitute your `$..transactionId` JSON Path Expression with this one:

```
$..transactionId[0]
```

It should remove these [JSON Array](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) brackets and you will see `223` only as the `${transactionId}` variable value

See [Advanced Usage of the JSON Path Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter) article for more tips on working with JSON response types.

Answer (score 1):

In `JMeter 3.1` version on-wards, try with following `JSON Path expression` using `JSON Extractor` (which is built-in)

```
JSON Path expression: $.transactionId
Match No: 1
```

gave me `265` value. with out double quotes, without array symbol.

Json extractor screenshot:

[image]

View results tree screenshot

[image]

Comment: in this case nothing passed in Body Data
in both cases in body data it shows like 
TransactionId":,

Comment: no it doesn't
form first api call response data has "transactionId": "265",
with may code it show in the next api call "transactionId": ["265"],

Comment: could you please share the screenshot of your latest trial? Used capital `T & I`. pls check which suites the best in the expression. that might be the issue

Comment: Updated answer. Add `Debug Sampler` and try to verify what is the value being captured in `transactionId` variable. you can use either `jp@gc - JSON Path Extractor` plugin OR `JSON Extractor` builtin