# jmeter raises thread exception when single user patch after post

Tags: python, django, jmeter, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am setting up a test against single EC2 instance. In that EC2 it has only Django application. It has no S3/CloundFront or RDS assist it. Everything purely run on Docker and basic setup of memory and CPU.

My goal is I want to see the empirical performance of my single EC2. It will help me do roughly cost estimation on the production.

**You can skip this and jump to my problem:**
Here is my production setup
1 load balance
2 nodes with identical setup by using docker image
1 bucket/cloudfront
1 rds

**Softwares:**
django==2.0.5
djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0
djangorestframework==3.8.2

**Tools:**
JMeter 4.0 r1823414
<strike>javac 10.0.1</strike>
<strike>java 10.0.1 2018-04-17</strike>
<strike>Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)</strike>
<strike>Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)</strike>

java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
javac 1.8.0_171

**Parameters:**

Thread Group
- Number of Threads: `10`
- Ramp-up period: `1`
- Loop Count: `1`

HTTP Header Manager
- `Content-Type`, `Application/json`
- `Authorization: jwt ${token}`

HTTP Request
- `http`
- `localhost`
- port: `8000`
- `POST`
- Path: `/api-token-auth/`
- Body data : `{"username": "myname", "password": "mysecretpassword"}`

At this point test is good. All are green I can have `token` back from `Django`.

**Problem:**

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: localhost:8000 failed to respond
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:141)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:165)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$5.doReceiveResponse(HTTPHC4Impl.java:401)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:842)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:581)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:67)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1231)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1220)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

*Additional Parameters*
JSON Extractor
- `Main sample only`
- Names of created variables: `token`
- JSON Path expressions: `$.token`
- Match No. (0 for Random): `1`

HTTP Request
- `http`
- `localhost`
- `port: 8000`
- `PATCH`
- `/api/branches/5/`
- Body Data: `{"name": "Bangkok"}`

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42151962/jmeter-how-to-use-extracted-value-from-response-in-body-data-of-another-reques#42166195) But I could not get it work. Here is my navigator bar
[image: nav bar jmeter]

**Debug Sampler:**
Jmeter's `token` is empty

```
JMeterVariables:
JMeterThread.last_sample_ok=false
JMeterThread.pack=org.apache.jmeter.threads.SamplePackage@79e6c86e
START.HMS=095906
START.MS=1526612346142
START.YMD=20180518
TESTSTART.MS=1526639371341
__jm__Users__idx=0
__jmeter.USER_TOKEN__=Users 1-1
token=
token_matchNr=0
```

**Questions:**
How to let `jmeter` grab `jwt` token and shoot another endpoints?

**Update1:**
When I disable `Patch Branch`. Debug Sampler does show me the `token` value

**Update2:**
I was wrongly call the variable. But `PATCH` problem still persist. Now I can call `token`. Here is my `request`

```
PATCH http://localhost:8000/api/branches/5/

PATCH data:
{
    "name": "Bangkok"
}


[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Autorization: jwt eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxMCwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJ0b255b2QiLCJleHAiOjE1MjY2NzIzOTMsImVtYWlsIjoidG9ueW9kQG1teC5jb20iLCJvcmlnX2lhdCI6MTUyNjY0MzU5M30.mjKJ2sRFx26pyChET1ORzLmv6umL7B1_Sy8wnNJO-iQ
Content-Type: Application/json
Content-Length: 26
Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/10.0.1)
```

**Update3:**
Problem seems to be `jmeter` side because. When I open the backend log.
`PATCH` never reach the backend

```
INFO|18/May/2018 11:52:04|"POST /api-token-auth/ HTTP/1.1" 200 224
INFO|18/May/2018 12:01:35|"POST /api-token-auth/ HTTP/1.1" 200 224
```

**Update:4**
Found the clue. It might be the problem from `HTTPClient4`

**Update:5**
Try imitate the original java8 environment. It raises the same problem
https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi

http://www.jmeter-archive.org/org-apache-http-NoHttpResponseException-td5719349.html

Answer (score 1):

Since when you uncheck "Use KeepAlive"  it works, it means the Connection becomes stale most probably because the JMeter defaults are not working for your use case.

You need to adjust :

- httpclient4.idletimeout
- httpclient4.validate_after_inactivity : Reduce it
- httpclient4.time_to_live

See:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html

Comment: Thank you for very much for answer. It is a good starting point for me to adjust the parameter. Jmeter is huge!

Answer (score 0):

oleg does [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558791/apache-httpclient-interim-error-nohttpresponseexception#10600762) to my problem. I have to uncheck `Use KeepAlive`